# Unable to Disconnect GitHub from Azure Repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-synapse

I am trying to disconnect from Azure Repository, but I'm unsure what to enter for the workpsace. As you can see I have entered 'workspace_publish', but I'm still not given the option to Disconnect

[image]

I have tried entering the list from Repository type through to Last Published Commit, but none allows me to disconnect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is difficult to understand with the provided screenshot, but this workspace name should refer to the sql pool name and not the branch name. try the workspace of sql pool

Comment: Probably a silly question but where can I find workspace of the sql pool?

Comment: When you look at the sql pool resources, it is shown on the front page on Essentials.

Comment: I thought the workspace name would have been either the repository name or the Publish branch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter the name of your Synapse workspace. The following is an example of how you can disconnect.

- The following is the image which shows the name of my synapse workspace and the connected Github workspace.

[image]

- After clicking disconnect you can enter the name of the workspace to complete the action

[image]